# firebase emulator localhost 500 showing error after updating firebase to latest version

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

after updating to 'Windows 11, version 22H2' and firebase, Local server: http://localhost:5000 is not working showing error 'Cannot GET /' cannot point out what went wrong
happening with all my older peojects also
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

need to add

```
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }
  ]
```

in firebase.json
under hosting